# Read "Show Notification" setting for my application (on Android 4.2+)

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, toast

Is it possible to read the "Show Notification" setting on Android 4.2 to check if the user had disabled this setting for my app?

I want to show an alert dialog as a fallback to a toast if the user has chosen to enable this setting.

Comment: I don't think so. I would have expected a flag in `ApplicationInfo` if it were exposed to us, and I do not see one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much searching and as CommonsWare said, it does seem like Android does not expose this setting to apps.